# Как в Disnake сделать чтобы бот определял айди канала в который отправлена команда, чтобы после отправить сообщение в него же?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Вот мои скромный попытки

```
@commands.slash_command(
    name="cats",
    description="Отправляет котика <3"
)
async def ping(self, inter):
    guild = disnake.utils.get(self.bot.guilds)
    channel = disnake.utils.get(self.bot.get_all_channels(), )
    cats = random.choice(cats_picture)
    with open(f"{cats}", "rb") as fp:
        await inter.response.defer()
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await inter.delete_original_message()
        await channel.send(file=disnake.File(fp, f"{cats}"))
```

Просто дело в том что я не могу просто взять айди и вписать его, ибо хочу чтобы бот мог работать на всех серверах, а не только на определённом. Очень надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо!